# How to restart Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint

I have PostgreSQL `9.3` and `9.4` installed on my ***Linux Mint*** machine.

***How can I restart PostgreSQL 9.4?***

A method to restart both versions together is also fine.

Comment: Have you searched the web? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/898303/Installing-and-Configuring-PostgreSQL-on-Linux-Min

Comment: I suggest migrating your data to 9.4 and remove the 9.3 installation afterwards.

Comment: @kometen The referenced article doesn't provide a way to selectively start and stop each and every single instance.

Comment: @JanHenke I wouldn't suggest anything outside the scope of the question. Anyway, v9.5 is the current stable version.

Comment: @Enzo He said he has both version running in parallel. So I just suggested migrating to the newer of the two, which would also fix the problem, as there would be only one postgresql left.

Comment: I also have 2 versions (used to be 3) in order to be able to support 2 different setups.

Comment: `systemctl restart postgresql` worked for me: it restarted _both_ of my installed running versions.

Comment: This answer solves the problem in latest versions
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67754783/5084088

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Try this as root (maybe you can use `sudo` or `su`):

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Without any argument the script also gives you a hint on how to restart a specific version

```
[Uqbar@Feynman ~] /etc/init.d/postgresql
Usage: /etc/init.d/postgresql {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ...]
```

Similarly, in case you [have it](https://serverfault.com/questions/867322/what-is-the-difference-between-service-and-systemctl), you can also use the `service` tool:

```
[Uqbar@Feynman ~] service postgresql
Usage: /etc/init.d/postgresql {start|stop|restart|reload|force reload|status} [version ...]
```

Please, pay attention to the optional `[version ...]` trailing argument.
That's meant to allow you, the user, to act on a specific version, in case you were running multiple ones. So you can restart version *X* while keeping version *Y* and *Z* untouched and running.

Finally, in case you are running [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), then you can use `systemctl` like this:

```
[Uqbar@Feynman ~] systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-11-14 12:33:35 CET; 7min ago
...
```

You can replace `status` with `stop`, `start` or `restart` as well as other actions. Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) for full details.
In order to operate on multiple concurrent versions, the syntax is slightly different. For example to **stop** `v12` and **reload** `v13` you can run:

```
systemctl stop postgresql-12.service
systemctl reload postgresql-13.service
```

Thanks to @Jojo for pointing me to this very one.
Finally Keep in mind that `root` permissions may be needed for non-informative tasks as in the other cases seen earlier.

Comment: could you give an example? the version number does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Have you tried, for example, "/etc/init.d/postgresql status 10"?

Comment: `systemctl` works on different versions of Postgresql. You can specify it with `systemctl status postgresql@13-main.service`. Replace 13 with the version number you want to address.

Comment: and if just `status postgresql` is 'exited' the real status will be `systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service`

Answer (score 71):

You can also restart postgresql by using this command, should work on both the versions:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: For me, if already running, this doesn't appear to do anything.
(doing "restart" instead of start in there does appear to work)

Answer (score 25):

**On Windows :**

1-Open Run Window by `Winkey + R`

2-Type `services.msc`

3-Search Postgres service based on version installed.

4-Click stop, start or restart the service option.

**On Linux :**

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

also instead of "restart" you can replace : stop or status.

Comment: OP says "I have Postgresql 9.3 and 9.4 installed on my Linux Mint machine."... Linux ... Now Windows!

Comment: @EnzoR my answer covers both Linux and Windows!!! is it wrong??
maybe someone need it :) do not take it hard dude

Comment: Not taking it hard. I 
The OP is about Linux and about 2 versions at the same time.
Your answer is about Windows and Linux and only one default version.
I simply say your answer is not hitting the spot.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

`sudo systemctl stop  postgresql`

`sudo systemctl start  postgresql`

Answer (score 4):

The right way to restart postgres server is to use

> pg_ctl restart -D /home/postgres/postgresdbdata/

***pg_ctl*** is usually found in location ***usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl*** if u dont have it added to your path.

Documentation can be found here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pg-ctl.html
This has more details on Start,Stop,Restart,etc of the postgres server.

Answer (score 1):

You can firstly check for the postgress process running

```
ps -ef | grep post
```

You might need to use (post|pg) on the grep side, to discover the process for the Postgres service running on your machine, it might depend on your OS.

And you can just kill the child process since most of this process should restart automatically.

```
sudo kill $pid_of_the_child_process
```

Answer (score 0):

**macOS:**

1. On the top left of the MacOS menu bar you have the Postgres Icon
2. Click on it this opens a drop down menu
3. Click on Stop -> than click on start

Comment: On macOS you have a top menu bar that generally stores that clock, search icon,... and some running mini apps that you can open up. And there you can see the elephant icon as well for postgres.

Comment: I use macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and the top menu doesn't show such an icon. But my database manager shows the Postgres server is active.

Comment: OP says "I have Postgresql 9.3 and 9.4 installed on my Linux Mint machine."... Linux ... Now macOS!

Answer (score 0):

With below shown steps I managed to restart Postgres server which located at  `/database/pgsql` directory and initially was started by another user

- find out the owner of the postgres directory. 
  `ls -l /database/pgsql` 
  in my case owner was **postgres** user.
- set Postgres data directory path, otherwise restart gives error about missing data directory path 
  `export PGDATA='/database/pgsql/data'`
- restart Postgres server with the following command. 
  `sudo -u postgres -E /database/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl restart` 
  -u runs command as postgres user -E includes current user environment variables so PGDATA
  variable value is visible to the command. to run command sudo permission needed.

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres 14

```
[root@95 pgsql]# service postgresql-14 status
```

Then you can replace status with start and stop.. To check version

```
[root@95 pgsql]# psql --version
```