# Migrating from SQLite to Postgres for deployment on Heroku. PG::ConnectionBad. Using Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, cloud9

I'm trying to migrate from SQLite to Postgres so the app deploys correctly on Heroku. But I'm not having any luck.

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I'm new to Postgres but I've tried every suggestion I've come across with no luck. Here's my database.yaml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  username: postgres 
  password: postgres

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

I believe I have the empty database setup correctly as it is in the Postgres list, but running rake db:migrate fails.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet run:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

in the cloud9 terminal

then switch to your postgres user and verify that you have the database you specified in your database.yaml created

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

then in the psql prompt enter the following command to list all available databases

```
\list
```

If you need to create a database you can do so by typing

```
CREATE DATABASE "database_name";
```

To set the password for the postgres user use

```
\password postgres
```

After going through the above steps make sure your database.yaml file has the correct *database name, username, and password* and try running

```
rake db:migrate
```

**If the database is setup correctly and the database.yaml file is configured**

Try restarting the postgres server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` again

**Sources**

Cloud9 [docs](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-postgresql/1573) related to setting up PostgresSQL

Cloud9 [Forum Post](https://community.c9.io/t/how-do-i-set-up-postgresql-on-c9-for-my-rails-app/2614/3?u=bradydowling) related to setting up PostgreSQL in a Rails app

Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-to-change-postgresql-user-password) related to changing psql password

Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918025/how-to-restart-postgresql) related to restarting the PostgreSQL server

**Alternative**
Another way I've managed to push apps that I've started developing with SQLite to heroku, is to move the SQLite gem into the development group in my Gemfile, and add a production group with the heroku dependencies:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails12_factor'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then in development bundle install without the production group:

```
bundle install --without production
```

And do normal bundle install when I push to heroku

Comment: Still no luck. Is there a chance template0 or template1 became corrupted? Is there any way to reset everything and start from scratch? I've been staring at the same error message for 3 days now.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, however I found some more information about it in a different thread about [Clobbered default database in PostgreSQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55792/clobbered-default-database-in-postgresql) which appears to state that template0 is protected

Comment: @Jason This thread recommends dropping clusters using `pg_dropcluster` and reinstalling, over performing a full purge [How to thoroughly purge and reinstall postgresql on ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu) Cloud9 development enviornment should be using Ubuntu I believe.

Comment: @Jason You should also try restarting the PostgreSQL server. I edited my response to include instructions. After logging into my own cloud9 environment today I received the same error you've been getting and restarting fixed it.